# Django, Borg pattern, API calls, caching results

Tags: python, django, api, caching

I'm using an API from a different site that returns a couple of 'pricepoint URL's that my users use to buy Virtual Goods.

I'm supposed to cache those results for at least an hour, since they don't change the price points on their system much. (And we want to save both our's and their bandwidth.)

After looking for singleton's in Python I discovered the borg pattern, which seems even cooler, so this is what i did:

```
def fetchPrices():
    #uses urllib2.urlopen() to fetch prices
    #parses results with ElementTree
    return prices

class PriceStore():
    __shared_state = {}

    def update(self):
        if self.lastUpdate is not None and (datetime.now() - self.lastUpdate).seconds >= 3600:
            self.prices = fetchPrices()
            self.lastUpdate = datetime.now()
        elif self.lastUpdate is not None:
            return
        else:
            self.lastUpdate = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
            self.update()

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        self.lastUpdate = None
        self.update()
```

The idea is to use this in the following way:

```
store = PriceStore()
url = store.prices['2.9900']['url']
```

And the store should initialize correctly and only fetch new price point info, if the existing info is older than one hour.

I seem to be hitting their API with every time that PriceStore is initialized, though. Can anyone spot my problem? Can I use a global variable like `__shared_state` in django and expect it to still contain pricing info?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks people! Sorry that 3 of you spotted my mistake at exactly the same time! You're all right of course. Is this the best way of caching an API result, or have you done something cooler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I seem to be hitting their API with
>   every time that PriceStore is
>   initialized, though. Can anyone spot
>   my problem?

Yep, it's easy to spot:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
    self.lastUpdate = None
```

the `self.lastUpdate = None` **absolutely guarantees** that the immediately following call to `self.update()` will find `self.lastUpdate`'s value to be `None` -- you just forced it to be so!

Remove that `self.lastUpdate = None` in the `__init__` and, for example, use instead a

```
lastUpdate = None
```

at **class body** level, e.g. just after the `__shared_state = {}` assignment and with the same alignment as that assignment.  *That* will make things work as you intend.

Comment: D'OOH! Thanks. I must have put that in when I was debugging it and it didn't have a price object at first.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that when you create a new PriceStore, you set self.lastUpdate to None (in your second-to-last line).  So although they all share state, every new object clobbers the state.

Instead do this:

```
class PriceStore():
    __shared_state = {'lastUpdate': None}
```

Another problem you might face is that depending on how your Django is deployed, you may be using more than one process.  Each one would have its own copy of the shared state.

Comment: wouldn't this hard-code 'lastUpdate' to always be None, too? No, thinking about it, this probably works, too. Since {} doesn't mean __shared_state is always empty. So will my code simply overwrite that None and save it? Yeah, i'm not sure about mod_wsgi's setup on my machine either, but even if there are 4 apache processes I think the api won't blacklist me for a call every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In `__init__` you set `self.lastUpdate = None`. Don't do that.

Specifically, consider the following code:

```
A = PriceStore()

# some time later

B = PriceStore()
```

Now A.lastUpdate == None, which you didn't want! Instead, try

```
if "lastUpdate" not in self.__dict__:
    self.lastUpdate = None
```

That way you never overwrite it.